# Test Watch OS 1 App in Xcode 7 Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode7-beta4

How can I test a Watch OS 1 app in El Capitan? Xcode 6.4 constantly crashes, and Xcode 7 doesn't seem to support Watch OS 1 simulators.

Comment: Check this out to get your Xcode 6.4 working again: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/37126 - Also, it's really hard to rely on beta software.

Answer (score 0):

try in terminal for XCode 7 beta 4:`

```
cd /Applications/Xcode-beta.app (or wherever your Xcode 7 beta 4 is located)

cd Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform

cd Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/usr/lib

sudo mv dyld_sim dyld_sim.orig
```

Comment: I actually ended up solving the problem by doing something similar to this except with Xcode 6.4, not Xcode 7 Beta.

Comment: Just make sure you undo that after you update to the next OS X beta.